# Are fonts standardized?

Tags: fonts

I was informed in my Adobe program that I didn't have a font called "LucidaGrande". I went on google and found a site that was offering it.

Based off its name, LucidaGrande seems like it's a rather "standardized"/common font. Is it possible that there are multiple versions of LucidaGrande out there, or is there some type of standardization or font-copyright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are definitely subject to copyright. As a created work they are automatically copyrighted by their creator. This covers the name and the shape of the font.

This means that you cannot:

1. Create a font that looks identical to "LucidaGrande" and call it something else.
2. Create a font that looks different to "LucidaGrande" and call it "LucidaGrande".

What this does mean is that you'll find a lot of fonts that look *almost* the same, often called slightly different names to get round both of these issues.

Comment: ["In the United States, typefaces, as such, are excluded from copyright protection"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property_protection_of_typefaces) scalable fonts are protected. Laws on Fonts vary from place to place.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from this [microsoft website](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/) Lucida Grande seems to be an apple mac osx font. I checked my windows system and it is not installed.